# PHP OOP - How to validate input fields correctly

Tags: php, html, templates, tags

This is my Form - This an Include File.

**form_file.php**

```
<section class="container-sm">
   <form method="post" class="par-form">
        <h3 class="par-h2">John Doe Form</h3>

         <p><label class="single-label" for='user_firstname'>Name: <a id='user_firstname_label'></a></label>
                
         <input class="par-input form_login" maxlength="15" name="user_firstname" required value="<?=$obVaga->user_firstname?>" ></input><span class="error">*<?php echo $nameErr;?></span></p>

         <p><label class="single-label" for='user_secondname'>Surname: <a id='user_secondname_label'></a></label>
              
         <input class="par-input form_login" maxlength="40" name="user_secondname" required value="<?=$obVaga->user_secondname?>" ></input></p>
              
         <p><label  class="single-label" for='user_email'>E-mail: <a id='user_email_label'></a></label>
              
         <input class="par-input form_login" maxlength="40" name="user_email" required value="<?=$obVaga->user_email?>" ></input></p>

         <button type="button" onclick="sendData()" class="par-button" id='user_button_sendData'>SEND</button>
        </form>
</section>
```

This is the template page that receives the Form file

**single-add.php**

```
<?php 
/**
 * Acess the composer library
 */
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
/**
 * Use a Classe VAGA
 */
use \App\Entity\Vaga; 

$obVaga = new Vaga;

    if (isset($_POST['user_firstname'],$_POST['user_secondname'],$_POST['user_email'])) {

    $obVaga->user_firstname     = $_POST['user_firstname'];
    $obVaga->user_secondname    = $_POST['user_secondname'];
    $obVaga->user_email         = $_POST['user_email'];
    $obVaga->user_cadastrar();
    } 

?>
                
        <!-- Receive the contents of the form include form_file.php  -->
        <?php include __DIR__.'/appincludes/form_file.php' ?>
```

This is the Class page that receives the data

**Vaga.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Entity;

/**
 * Use a Classe Database
 */
use \App\Db\Database;
use PDO;


class Vaga{

    // @var Integer
    public $user_id;

    // @var String
    public $user_firstname;

    // @var String
    public $user_secondname;

    // @var String 
    public $user_email;

    // @var String 
    public $nameErr;

    // @var Boolean

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["user_firstname"])) {
      $nameErr = "Name is required";
    } else {
      $name = test_input($_POST["user_firstname"]);
      // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
      if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-' ]*$/",$name)) {
        $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
      }
    }
    
    if (empty($_POST["user_secondname"])) {
        $nameErr = "Name is required";
      } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["user_secondname"]);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-' ]*$/",$name)) {
          $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["user_email"])) {
      $emailErr = "Email is required";
    } else {
      $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
      // check if e-mail address is well-formed
      if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
      }
    }
}


    public function user_cadastrar(){
        // DEFINIR A DATA
        // INSERT STRINGs IN THE TABLE 
        $obDatabase = new Database('tb_partner'); 

        $this->id = $obDatabase->insert([
                                'user_firstname' => $this->user_firstname,
                                'user_secondname'=> $this->user_secondname,
                                'user_email'    => $this->user_email
                            ]);
    }
 
}
```

I´m trying to use this script to validate the fields, but I am stuck. I`m trying to execute this script through the class file Vaga.php

```
public function par_add_validate(){
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["user_firstname"])) {
      $nameErr = "Name is required";
    } else {
      $name = test_input($_POST["user_firstname"]);
      // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
      if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-' ]*$/",$name)) {
        $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
      }
    }
    
    if (empty($_POST["user_secondname"])) {
        $nameErr = "Name is required";
      } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["user_secondname"]);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-' ]*$/",$name)) {
          $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["user_email"])) {
      $emailErr = "Email is required";
    } else {
      $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
      // check if e-mail address is well-formed
      if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
      }
    }
};
}
```

I putted the Var $nameErr in the form_file.php where it should display an echo string IF the field is empty or with not acceptable letters.

This is the result in the debug.log file:

> [18-Aug-2021 16:44:07 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: nameErr in C:\xampppserver2\htdocs\project\appincludes\form_file.php on line 15

Line 15:

```
<input name="user_firstname" required value="<?=$obVaga->user_firstname?>" ></input><span>*<?php echo $nameErr;?></span></p>
```

What am I doing wrong or what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have some lines missing here:

> ```php
>     // @var Boolean
>
> if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
> ```

Otherwise you've put some logic code right inside your class (without method) which should result in a Parse error. Also why is there `@var Boolean` with no boolean property following?

Given that you wrap all that code in a method, you still have several issues. First, you can't access `$nameErr` directly. Instead, you want `$this->nameErr`.

And in `form_file.php` you also have no variable called `$nameErr`. You have `nameErr` as a property of `$obVaga` object though. You can access it using `$obVaga->nameErr`.

Comment: Hello @rept1d, i did all the changes in the file as you suggest and some tests. Nothing happens. Even a error message in the debug.log file i don`t receive it.